# Distribution and expectation of inverse of a random Bernoulli matrix

Tags: pr.probability, matrices, probability-distributions, random-matrices, matrix-theory

This question cropped up as a part of my research. Let us assume a $n\times n$ random matrix $\mathbf{M}$ with elements iid distributed to a Bernoulli distribution that takes values $\{0,1\}$ with probability $ \ p = 1/2$.

What I want to know is that what sort of distribution would $\mathbf{M}^{-1}$ have? and what could its possible expectation be?

[I have posted this question on math.stackexchange too.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4033301/487657)

Comment: There is no reason for the inverse to have entries in $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Ah yes, I realized that.

Comment: It seems from row reduction method that the entries of inverse matrix are in $\{±\frac{p}{q}, 0, ±k\}$, for a $n×n$ matrix. Here, $0<p<n-1, 0<q≤n-1 , 0<k≤n-1 $.

Comment: Please don't post in both places so close together. :-)

Comment: oh should I delete the one on stackexchange?